# How to modify the root context for NiFi's web UI

Tags: apache-nifi

When launching NiFi, it's default root context is nifi so it's URL looks like:

```
http://localhost:8080/nifi/
```

I need to be able to support the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/custom/nifi/
```

Is there a way to make this configuration in NiFi? If needed I can make source code modifications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best approach would be to run NiFi behind a reverse proxy that exposes your custom context-path as the public facing address and routes to NiFi backends that are running NiFi on the default context-path.

NiFi supports URL rewriting for reverse-proxies using X-Forwarded-* headers passed from the proxy, including the context path, which can be passed in the `X-Forwarded-Context` or `X-Forwarded-Prefix` header.

For more information, see the [NiFi Admin Guide - Proxy Configuration](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#proxy_configuration).

You may also find the configuration examples (both for NiFi and the Reverse Proxy) in this GitHub repository useful: [ijokarumawak/nifi-reverseproxy](https://github.com/ijokarumawak/nifi-reverseproxy)